# How come my array isn't updating after a splice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here is my code

```js
    var reactions = ['','','' ]; // Valid reactions for filter
    var participants = []; // People attending the event
    // Sending the embed back and then . . .
    message.channel.send(eventEmbed)
    .then(embedMessage => {
        // Adding the reactions after the embed has been created
        embedMessage.react("");
        embedMessage.react("");
        embedMessage.react("");
        // Reaction Collector to gather the users attending the event.
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return !user.bot && reactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name);
        };
    
        rc = new Discord.ReactionCollector(embedMessage, filter);

        rc.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            if(reaction.emoji.name === "")
            {
                let new_user = true;
                // Check if they are already on the list
                for (let participant in participants)
                {
                    if (user.id === participants[participant].id) // If user is found in the list, remove them and update.
                    {
                        console.log(participant);
                        console.log(participants);
                        //console.log(participants.splice(user,1)); // Remove user from the list
                        participants.splice(user,1);
                        console.log(participants);
                        reaction.users.remove(user); // Reset reaction count back to 1
                        // Update the embed
                        eventEmbed.fields.find(f => f.name === "Participants").value = participants; // Updating participants
                        embedMessage.edit(eventEmbed);
                        new_user = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else // continue to loop through the whole list
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
// Blah blah blah . . .
```

I printed the splice line and it seems to be working, but for some reason its not updating? I am just curious as to why this is.

Also, here is the output. In this case, a user object that is already in the participants list is found, and so the splice is executed.

```
0 //Index 0
[ //Participants list
  User {
    id: '348298943014371338',
    username: 'Caweb',
    bot: false,
    discriminator: '8740',
    avatar: 'a_413ca01ea08214480c35aff45c54647a',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 256 },
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  }
]
[] // The console.log(participants.splice(user,1)) line. So it seems to look like its splicing successfully!
[  // But then it still shows the user here :(
  User {
    id: '348298943014371338',
    username: 'Caweb',
    bot: false,
    discriminator: '8740',
    avatar: 'a_413ca01ea08214480c35aff45c54647a',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 256 },
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) actually returns an array of the elements they *did* splice, meaning your function is not working at all. This is probably because `user` is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object instead of an index.

> #### Syntax
>
> ```js
> let arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
> ```

If I'm reading your code correctly, you actually want the first argument to be `participant` instead of `user`, as `participant` is the actual index you'd like to splice.

```js
participants.splice(participant, 1);
```